# Is it possible to get anchor value with url rewriting rules?

Tags: php, apache, url-rewriting

I am trying to create a website which the content will be refresh by anchor changes.

It works fine, but if the user tries an url directly, the website set the index page, this is normal.

I would like the user will be redirect to the content by getting the anchor value and send it in a GET value with url-rewriting rule.

for example:

change:
   http://www.mywebsite.fr/fr/#!page-title-30002000782

to:
   http://www.mywebsite.fr/fr/?content=page-title-30002000782

Is it possible ?

I know that it can be done wiht javascript, but I afraid that the url will be ignore by google boot.

Comment: No, that is not possible - because the hash part of the URL is not send to the server in the first place.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I will triy an other way.